# Префикс "mb_" у функций в php

Tags: php

Есть две функции измерения длины строки:

- `strlen()`
- `mb_strlen()`

Что значит этот префикс и есть ли еще какие-то префиксы и что они значат?

Comment: Вы можете получить описание любой функции, набрав в адресной строке php.net/имя_функции. Там всё отлично расписано, с примерами и комментариями. Например http://php.net/mb_strlen

Comment: смотрите документацию, если ну ОЧЕНЬ грубо – первая для латиницы, вторая для кириллицы

Answer (score 4):

какой-либо специальной синтаксической «нагрузки» символы подчёркивания в названиях [функций](http://php.net/manual/ru/indexes.functions.php) в языке *php* не несут. это просто часть имени функции, которая, например, может «разделять» слова, составляющие имя функции.

конкретно префикс `mb_` в названии функции на языке *php* принято использовать для функций, способных обрабатывать [многобайтные строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php).

обзор информации о работе с многобайтными строками в php: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php

Comment: так в чем различие между этими функциями?

Comment: теми, что вы привели в вопросе? первая из них будет некорректно работать с многобайтными строками.

Answer (score 2):

**mb == multi-byte**

mb_* функции умеют работать с разными кодировками. *В том числе* с мультибайтными.

Кодировку можно указывать явно в дополнительном параметре или настроить "кодировку по умолчанию" один раз в начале скрипта через mb_internal_encoding()

http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php